# How to override scss variables?

Tags: css, variables, sass

I am currently using materialize.css and I want to override the default variables so that the main file remain unchanged. What I am trying in my main stylesheet.scss is like

```
@import '_materialize';
@import '_modified';
@import '_new';
```

In my _modified file I am setting

```
$secondary-color: color("blue", "darken-1");
```

In materialize.scss, _variable.scss is already imported (default framework file) in which secondary color value is

```
$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
```

Still secondary color remain teal.How to override with external scss file like this one?

**Edit-1: Found the solution.**

```
$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
```

was not working due to not loading color mixin file of materialize css.

After `@import "materialize/components/color";` in modified.scss and then

```
$secondary-color:color("teal", "lighten-5");
```

works now.

Comment: have you tried `!important;` behind the color like this: `$secondary-color: color("blue", "darken-1") !important;`?

Comment: That's interesting, I would have thought that would work. Have you tried, putting your `modified` file first? The `!default` flag in `materialize` means that the value will only be set if it hasn't already been set. Also, a fun fact - you can omit the `_` from your file name when you import it, Sass knows that it is a partial.

Comment: Putting modified on top of _materialize gives error in bracket editor compiler

Comment: Where is the `$secondary-color` applied? Is it before you change it's value?

Comment: It is applied throughout all materialize framework scss files but if I put _modified on top editor gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import your vars first (not last):

```
@import '_your-vars'; // your own vars
@import '_materialize'; // includes framework vars
... // other modifications
```

As far as I understand the SCSS `!default` flag: it's a fallback, when nothing has been declared before. So when you import your variables (only the variables, no other modifications which might have dependencies) first, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

See below examples

```
 $secondary-color: color("blue", "darken-1");
 .someClass{
      $secondary-color: color("teal", "darken-1") !important;
      .someClass h2{
            color: $secondary-color;
      }
 }
```